# How can i have counter for php preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

```
function getContent($xml,$tag,$id="") {
    if ($id=="") {
        $tag_regex = '/<'.$tag.'[^>]*>(.*?)<\/'.$tag.'>/si';
    } else {
        $tag_regex = '/<'.$tag.'[^>]*id=[\'"]'.$id.'[\'"]>(.*?)<\/'.$tag.'>/si';
    }
    preg_match($tag_regex,$xml,$matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$omg = file_get_contents("Generated/index.php");
$extract = getContent($omg,"div","lolz2");
echo $extract;
```

For example i have something like this. And html have something like this inside:

```
<div id="lolz">qwg1eqwe</div>
<div id="lolz1"><div id='lolz2'>qwdqw2cq</div>asd3qwe</div>
```

If we search for id lolz we get the correct answer, but if we search for lolz1 we stop at first `</div>` that's inner `<div id="lolz2">`. It's possible to keep something like counter for preg_match that's will keep how many `<div>`'s i pass till i find `</div>`?

Comment: Please use branches, they're your friend!

Answer (score 1):

HTML isn't a regular language, so building something like that would be overkill and is the job of an HTML parser. Please see: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

The reason your code was failing however was because you were using both single and double quotes in your input but your regex didn't account for it. This works for me:

```
function getContent($xml,$tag,$id="") {
    if ($id=="") {
        $tag_regex = '/<'.$tag.'[^>]*>(.*?)<\/'.$tag.'>/si';
    } else {
        $tag_regex = '/<'.$tag.'[^>]*id=[\\\'"]'.$id.'[\\\'"]>(.*?)<\/'.$tag.'>/si';;
    }
    preg_match($tag_regex,$xml,$matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$omg = '<div id="lolz">qwg1eqwe</div>
<div id="lolz1"><div id="lolz2">qwdqw2cq</div>asd3qwe</div>';
$extract = getContent($omg,"div","lolz2");
var_dump($extract);
```

As long as you don't have nested elements this code will work and you won't need to use a DOM parser, though you really should for anything more complicated that *might* be nested (e.g. you don't have control over the input).

Comment: This should be a comment. Merely linking to another answer is not an answer.

Comment: Funy post, so you are telling me to dont use preg_match for that? I guess i could do same thing with reading byte-byte html code. That would be a solution?

Comment: Dude, no it's dont working. Same thing, in first `</div>` it's stop reading content.

Comment: It will work for lolz2, but not lolz1 for the reason I state at the end of the answer :)

Comment: Well ok, but it's not answer to problem, just target :)

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php and http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/